# api for transfer to manufacturing in Oracle apps

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apps

I am trying to find api or interface table to do the "transfer to Manufacturing" in Oracle apps.

I tried the following 4 ways, but no luck:

1. mtl_system_items_interface interface table
2. apps.ego_item_pub.process_item public api
3. ENG_BOM_RTG_TRANSFER_PKG.ENG_BOM_RTG_TRANSFER private api which result in
4. ENG_ECO_PUB.Process_ECO API

Can anyone guide me with some example, how to do this via api?

Tried the ECO https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=349161821206184&id=1242524.1&_adf.ctrl-state=qaus6q7ko_7…
in this document, the point no. 7 is something related to my requirement.

> 7. How to Transfer Engineering Items, Bills and Routing to Manufacturing using ENG_ECO_PUB.Process_ECO API ?
>      Engineering Items, Bills, Routing required to be transferred to Manufacturing can be added to an ECO. Once the ECO is implemented, all these entities will be transferred from Engineering to Manufacturing and respective fields will be updated. (MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B.ENG_ITEM_FLAG / BOM_STRUCTURES_B.ASSEMBLY_TYPE Engineering to Manufacturing )
>      -- Create ECO and revised items to be transferred to Mfg
>      L_Eco_Rec.Change_Type_Code := 'ECO';
>      l_eco_rec.approval_list_name := NULL; -- No approval required
>      L_Eco_Rec.Approval_Status_Name:= 'Approved';  -- will default to Not submitted for Approval
>      l_eco_rec.Status_Name := 'Open';  -- Status
>      l_eco_rec.description := 'ECO - '||l_eco_rec.eco_name||' API Test';
>      l_eco_rec.transaction_type := 'CREATE';
>      l_eco_rec.plm_or_erp_change := 'ERP';
>      l_eco_rec.return_status := NULL;
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).eco_name := 'ECO100';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).organization_code := 'M1';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).revised_item_name := 'TEST_REV_ITEM1';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).new_revised_item_revision := 'B';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).start_effective_date := sysdate;
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).status_type := 1; -- 'Open'
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).change_description :=  'ECO - Transfer';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).transaction_type := 'CREATE'; -- transaction type : CREATE / UPDATE
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).Transfer_Or_Copy         := 'T';
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).Transfer_OR_Copy_Item    := 1;        -- transfer items
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).Transfer_OR_Copy_Bill    := 1;        -- transfer Bill
>      l_revised_item_tbl(l_row_cnt).Transfer_OR_Copy_Routing    := 1;     -- transfer Routing

I tried but received the following errors in log:

> organization_code: AGM
>   organization_id: 105
>   The following objects will be processed as part of the same business object
>   | ECO           : ECO100
>   | ECO REVISIONS : 0
>   | CHANGE LINES  : 0
>   | REVISED ITEMS : 1
>   | REVISED COMPS : 0
>   | SUBS. COMPS   : 0
>   | REFD. DESGS   : 0
>   | OPERATION     : 0
>   | RESOURCE      : 0
>   | SUB RESOURCE  : 0
>
> PVT API: Calling ECO_Header return_status: S return_status: S Within
>   the Log Error Procedure . . . Scope: Entity Index: 1 Error Level: 0
>   Error Status: U Other Status: N Other Message: Business Object: ECO
>   Translating and Inserting Messages . . . Entity Id: BO Message Count
>   on this point : 1 Finished extracting other message . . . Other
>   Message generated: Error Level is Business Object . . . Status
>   unexpected and scope is All . . . Error Level is ECO . . . Setting
>   Revised Item  records to N Setting Revised component records to N
>   Scope=All in Revised Component Setting reference designator records to
>   N Setting substitute component records to N Setting Revised operation
>   records to N Scope=All in Operation Sequences Setting Opration Rsource
>   records to N Setting sub operation resources records to N

Do anyone know about these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

there is a long silence when I google for "api for transfer to manufacturing in oracle apps", and the same here in this forum. Another thing that I was fear about is that if the question is not answered then I will be kick off from here once again.

here the solution we made:

```
Declare
    l_inventory_item_id number := 5838015;
    l_org_id number :=105;
    l_resp_id number;
    l_appl_id number;
begin
    select responsibility_id, application_id
    into l_resp_id, l_appl_id
    from fnd_responsibility
    where responsibility_key = 'INVENTORY_SUPER_USER';

    --initialize user session
    fnd_global.apps_initialize(
        user_id => fnd_global.user_id,
        resp_id => l_resp_id,
        resp_appl_id => l_appl_id);

APPS.ENG_BOM_RTG_TRANSFER_PKG.ENG_BOM_RTG_TRANSFER
(
X_org_id            => l_org_id,
X_eng_item_id           =>l_inventory_item_id,
X_mfg_item_id           =>l_inventory_item_id,
X_transfer_option   => 2,
X_designator_option     => 1,
X_alt_bom_designator        => NULL,
X_alt_rtg_designator        => NULL, 
X_effectivity_date      => sysdate,
X_last_login_id         => -1,
X_bom_rev_starting      => NULL,
X_rtg_rev_starting      => NULL,
X_ecn_name      =>  'ABC.ABC_11377_121',
X_item_code         => 1,
X_bom_code          => 2,
X_rtg_code          => 1,
X_mfg_description   =>  NULL,
X_segment1          => NULL,
X_segment2          => NULL,
X_segment3          => NULL,
X_segment4          => NULL,
X_segment5          => NULL,
X_segment6          => NULL,
X_segment7          => NULL,
X_segment8          => NULL,
X_segment9          => NULL,
X_segment10         => NULL,
X_segment11         => NULL,
X_segment12         => NULL,
X_segment13         => NULL,
X_segment14         => NULL,
X_segment15         => NULL,
X_segment16         => NULL,
X_segment17         => NULL,
X_segment18         => NULL,
X_segment19         => NULL,
X_segment20         => NULL,
X_implemented_only      =>1,
X_unit_number           => NULL,
X_commit           => TRUE);
end;
```

After this code, you can check the eng_item_flag = 'N' and engineering_date should be sysdate.